# React, is using UI framework still benefical when you to customize styles heavily?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, semantic-ui

For instance, material-ui gives you look of material design.

When you are creating a website whose design has nothing to do with material ui, is it a sensible choice to use material-ui as a ui framework?

I see ui frameworks generally have more components such as sidebar, navbar which are quite tedious to implement, so I see the benefits of using the frameworks.

But our team member who is responsible for applying the design to react components, has an opinion that ui-framework oftentimes causes more trouble to arrive at the design he's given.

Is there a way of utilizing the functionality of sophisticated components of ui-framework and yet has minimum friction customizing the style?

Maybe is there a `zeroing-out` all the styles of a ui-framework down to basics (I wonder if this makes sense)?

Answer (score 2):

Yep it's a sensible question. It's a shame that so much work goes into the functionality of the library components, but then you're locked into the MaterialUI look and feel.

If the site hasn't been designed as a MaterialUI site (i.e. the designer hasn't strictly followed the MaterialUI design guidelines) then your team member is correct, using a MaterialUI component library is probably a bad idea. I haven't personally heard of any "zeroing out" library, and generally these libraries are very hard to customise outside of just tweaking the theme.

A better approach imo would be to use high quality standalone React components that don't impose any specific style and are easily customisable to achieve any complex parts of the app. There are good choices available:

- [Downshift](https://github.com/downshift-js/downshift) for dropdowns/typeaheads/autocomplete
- [React Burger Menu](https://github.com/negomi/react-burger-menu) for sidebars
- [React Tiny Popover](https://github.com/alexkatz/react-tiny-popover) for tooltips and popovers
- [React Modal](https://github.com/reactjs/react-modal) for modals
- Etc

Answer (score 0):

A large portion of the Material-UI component code is related to implementing the Material Design looks. Though the styling is highly customizable, if you aren't aiming for a look that is at least somewhat aligned with Material Design, then you may be creating a lot of extra work for yourself if you need to significantly undo/override the default styling for most of the components.

That said, Material-UI components are structured in a manner where you may be able to leverage some of the lower-level building blocks to create your own components. For instance, [InputBase](https://material-ui.com/api/input-base/) and [ButtonBase](https://material-ui.com/api/button-base/) are building blocks used to create different types of inputs and buttons within Material-UI.

You can look at https://mui-treasury.com/ for some examples of significant customization of some Material-UI components.

Even if you don't leverage Material-UI components ("@material-ui/core"), you may still find considerable value in leveraging the [@material-ui/styles](https://next.material-ui.com/css-in-js/basics/) and [@material-ui/system](https://next.material-ui.com/system/basics/) packages to help with your own styling solution. And if you decide to create your own components, you can use the Material-UI source code as a useful resource on how to go about specific components.